# How to link phantomjs into selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have tried run selenium using phantomjs. But the script stop running without respond. How to run selenium using phantomjs?

Answer (score 0):

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS( executable_path='C:\location\of\phantomjs.exe' )

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
PhantomJSDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

Test1()
{

    //set binary path of phantomJS driver
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "drivers/phantomjs.exe");
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
    //intialize driver and set capabilties
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
    //intitlaize webdriverwait class
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
}
```